# add favicon.ico to apache cxf

Tags: cxf

Is there a clear explanation to add favicon.ico to apache cxf such that there is no such "can't find the request for localhost:8888/favicon.ico's Observers" error in the log. I know I can safely ignore this, but it'd be nice to know how I can actually add an icon for my web service.

Comment: I am in the same problem, and didn't find any way to solve it. As I can see following on my logs : [http-bio-8080-exec-1:WARN] org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController: Can't find the the request for http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico's Observer 
 an no favicon.co on browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized this is still a blocker for some people, so this is how I solved it.

In web.xml, I add a filter section to indicate my FaviconFilter. Something like this,

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>FaviconFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.foo.MyFaviconFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

In source code, I added `MyFaviconFilter` to implement `javax.servlet.Filter`. In the method `doFilter`, I manually inserted the array of bytes for `favicon.ico` to the output stream (you can use Base64 to decode string into array of bytes).

Hope this helps.